# Android application communicate with other devices Wifi but not the Internet, through 3g -Fi Internet?

Tags: android

Android application communicate with other devices Wifi but not the Internet, through 3g  Internet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what are you asking for... But if you wanna connect two device over 3g you have to create server on public IP with one of port. For that you can use Socket.IO for example. It's really simply and have implementation for web browsers, Android, iOS and even Windows Phone.

[Here](http://socket.io/demos/chat/) you have some Demo.

Comment: For Example I connect to A Hot spot but it not to connect internet,So I want to use 3g to connect internet.

Comment: Wify connect external devices , Android use 3g network  to Internet

Comment: Your question is totally  unclear.

Comment: I want to use Android phone connect external devices,but external devices    not connect internet,so I want to Android phone to connect external devices And can let My phone  connect internet.